# question about measure zero and discontinuities of a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed set, and say $E$ has measure zero. Let $g: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function where $Q$ is a box in $\mathbb{R}^n$. $E \subseteq Q $. Define

$$ A = \{ x \in E : g(x) \; \; \text{is discontinuous } \} $$

Does it follow that $A$ has measure zero?? or do I need to add more conditions? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is a subset of $E$.  It follows that $\mu(A) \leq \mu(E)$.  Thus, $\mu(A) = \mu(E) = 0$.

Comment: Why is $A$ a subset of $E$ ?

Comment: $A = \{ x \in E : g(x) \; \; \text{is discontinuous } \}$.  By definition, $x$ can only be in $A$ if it is also in $E$.  That is, $A \subseteq E$

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of a subtlety here. It does not immediately follow that the measure is 0 just because A is a subset of E, because there was no assumption that the measure is a complete measure. However if g is a measurable function then the set of points where g is discontinuous is measurable, and since it is a subset of a set with measure 0 it is also of measure 0. There was also no assumption that g was a measurable function though, so in this case, no it does not follow that A has measure zero in general